# Printing output of a spawned process results in a badly formatted output: why?

Tags: python, string, pexpect

I'm trying to execute a python program from another python program using the `pexpect` library, but I don't get the behavior I was expecting.

I would like the output of the first program (`prog1.py`) to be displayed in real time on the terminal of the second program (`prog2.py`). Using `child.after` I get the output badly formatted: all `\n` and `\r` are printed in output instead of being correctly used as end of line.

```
child = pexpect.spawn('python3 /home/robb/Workspace/prog1.py')

child.expect(".*do:")
child.sendline(sys.argv[1])
print(child.after)
```

I get all the output in one line:

```
b'Initializing database...\r\nDone initializing database!\r\n******************************\r\nProgram running\r\n******************************\r\n1. First Option\r\n2. Second Option\r\n\r\nPlease input number of action you want to do:'
```

Also, the answer to the question (the `sys.argv[1]`, in this case) does not even appear.
How to correctly display the output of `prog1`?

Using `print(child.before)` I get even a worse output, simply this:

```
b''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`child.after` returns you a `bytes` type instead of `str` that you would expect.

Convert the output into `str`

```
print(child.after.decode('utf8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The output is stored in `child.after` as a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) object. To get an ASCII output, decode it accordingly:

```py
print(child.after.decode('ascii'))
```

```
Initializing database...
Done initializing database!
******************************
Program running
******************************
1. First Option
2. Second Option

Please input number of action you want to do:
```